# GRAILS: findALL() vs FindBy---(params.id)

Tags: grails

Greeting everyone,

I am trying to pass a parameters from a URL to a findAll() method.

**LINE3** I use findAll() to define mouse.

**LINE2** def house will bring in the parameter DELAWARE when I go to the page: http://localhost:8080/TestApp/home/county/DELAWARE

House will only show one instance instead of a list.. is there anyway to pass the url instead of ["DELAWARE"]? (please see line 3) thanks :)

```
 def county() {
    def house = Home.findByCounty(params.id)  //sends only user related address to view
    def mouse = Home.findAll("from Home h where h.county= ?", ["DELAWARE"]);
    if (!house) {
    response.sendError(404)
    } else {

    [house:house, mouse:mouse ]
    }
}
```

**Working Code +1 @Danilo**

```
 def county() {
            def house = Home.findAllByCounty  (params.id)  //sends only county specified thru URL e.g. http://localhost:8080/TestAPP/home/county/DELAWARE
    if (!house) {
        response.sendError(404)
    } else {
            [house:house ]
        }
    }
```

Comment: I failed to understand what you want. honestly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findBy*` will return at most one row, if you want to get all rows use `findAllBy*`

In order to understand how the URL will be used by Grails you have to have a look at `conf/UrlMappings.groovy`. You may find something like this:

```
static mappings = {
    "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{
    }
}
```

this means that when you call `TestApp/home/county/DELAWARE` what Grails is trying to do is use the home controller (`HomeController`), invoking the county method (`def county(){...}`) and passing `DELAWARE` as `id`.

This should work correctly if inside county method of the `HomeController` you have:

```
def filteredInstances = Home.findAllByCounty(params.id)
```

Comment: findAllByCounty(params.id) did it, THANKS! +1